# How to show the dataframe in pyspark in presentable manner.

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

## command

df_load.describe().toPandas().transpose()

## The above command gives the following output. It is not possible to read the below output. Is there any way in jupyter notebook through which i can view the below dataframe in a tabular manner. I am running this code in jupyter notebook with "apachee toree-pyspark" kernel.

```
                                                    0     1       2  \
```

summary                                             count  mean  stddev
"fixed acidity";"volatile acidity";"citric acid...   1599  None    None

```
                                                                                                3  \
```

summary                                                                                           min
"fixed acidity";"volatile acidity";"citric acid...  10.1;0.27;0.54;2.3;0.065;7;26;0.99531;3.17;0.5...

```
                                                                                                4
```

summary                                                                                           max
"fixed acidity";"volatile acidity";"citric acid...  9;0.8;0.12;2.4;0.083;8;28;0.99836;3.33;0.65;10...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.

Comment: Somewhat ironic that you are asking a question about how to properly format your output and your question itself is poorly worded/hard to read. Please read [how can I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and try to fix the formatting.